# Automaitcally upload all files in one folder under the same name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google form with 4 fields.

Name
File upload 1
File upload 2
File upload 3
File upload 4

By default, when someone uploads a file on each file upload question it will create individual folders. What I intend to do is to automatically create a folder using the answer on the Name field. Then save all the uploaded files inside that folder and not on individual subfolders. Thank you

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this in specific, you will need to use Apps Script.

[This](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/upload-files) is a similar example of what you're looking for. I made some changes to adjust it to what you are asking for.

You can use the following script, just make sure to create the script from the Google Form you're using and update the `FOLDERID` in the script.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var mainFolder = "FOLDERID";  //FOLDERID will be the main folder where
  //folders from the answers will be created (You can use the one that Google Form creates by default)
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();

  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(mainFolder);
  var formName = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  var folder = getSubFolder_(destFolder, formName); //Checks if folder already exists

  // Gets the file upload response as an array to allow for multiple files.
  let fileUploads = itemResponses.filter((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD")
      .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse())
      .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);

    // Moves the files to the destination folder.
    if (fileUploads.length > 0) {
      fileUploads.forEach((fileId) => {
        DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(folder);
      });
    }
}

function getSubFolder_(objParentFolder, subFolderName) {
  // Iterates subfolders of parent folder to check if folder already exists.
  const subFolders = objParentFolder.getFolders();
  while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
    let folder = subFolders.next();

    // Returns the existing folder if found.
    if (folder.getName() === subFolderName) {
      return folder;
    }
  }
  // Creates a new folder if one doesn't already exist.
  return objParentFolder.createFolder(subFolderName)
}
```

**Last thing**, you need to add an OnSubmit trigger in the script editor.
[image]

After saving changes to the script and adding the trigger, you can test now by completing the Form, go to the folder you specified in the script and you will see the new folder with the files.

Basically you only need to change the `FOLDERID` in the script and add the OnSubmit trigger. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi @Lorena Gomez, I followed all the changes that you have recommended but for some reason, it still creates different subfolders for each document that is uploaded on each File Upload field. Also, I'm not sure if we have anywhere on the code that you have given when it will create a specific folder and rename it based on the answer on the first field on the form.

Comment: @user5500328 when respondents upload files through the Google Form, the files are stored in a fixed folder of your Google Drive and if you have multiple "File Upload" fields, 
 creates sub-folders under that fixed folder, as far as I know this can't be changed. So what happens here is that files are automatically stored in the fixed folder but with the script, files are moved to the new folder it creates with the name that respondent specifies in the Google Form.

Comment: @user5500328 I tested the script with a different account and it worked. So what I did, I created a folder in "My Drive", I copied the folder ID, pasted that in `FOLDERID` in the script, clicked on the "save" icon in Apps Script, added a trigger just as the screenshot I shared before, clicked on "Save", the "Sign in with Google" screen appeared, chose my account and clicked on "Allow". Finally I tested filling out a Google Form and the new folder was created in the folder I specified in `FOLDERID` and files were moved as well. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @user5500328 I just tested Lorena's solution and seems to be working for me, did it not work for you?